# Having difficulty updating object properties in basic actionscript program

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events

I'm still working my way through some pretty basic Actionscript programming (in Flex), and I'm getting a little caught up with events and object properties.

I've got 3 files below, one application and two components.  The basic goal is very simple - start out with two location canvases and one player canvas.  When clicking in one location canvas, the player will update it's x and y coords to that canvas.  Clicking in the other canvas will then update the player's x and y coordinates to that canvas.  Repeat.

I think I'm close, but I can't quite figure out how to get a click within location1 or location2 to send their respective x and y coordinates back to the playerX and playerY values.  Any suggestions about this specific issue, or even broader suggestions for accomplishing this more easily, would be great.

Here's my primary application file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
    xmlns:ns1="components.*">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            private var playerX:int = 20;
            [Bindable]
            private var playerY:int = 20;

            private function clickEventHandler(evt:Event):void
            {
                playerX = evt.x;
                playerY = evt.y;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <ns1:location x="139" y="168" id="location1"
        playerMove="clickEventHandler(event)"/>
    <ns1:location x="629" y="168" id="location2"
        playerMove="clickEventHandler(event)"/>
    <ns1:player x="{playerX}" y="{playerY}"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Here's my "location" component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="200" height="200"
    click="clickHandler()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           
            import flash.events.Events

            private function clickHandler():void
            {
                var moveClick:Event = new Event("playerMove");
                moveClick.x = target.x;
                moveClick.y = target.y;
                dispatchEvent(moveClick);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="playerMove")]
    </mx:Metadata>

</mx:Canvas>
```

And here's my player component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="50" height="100">    
</mx:Canvas>
```

UPDATE:

I've been able to simulate the desired effect with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            private var playerX:int = 20;
            [Bindable]
            private var playerY:int = 20;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Canvas x="139" y="168" id="location1" width="200" height="200"
        click="playerX = location1.x, playerY = location1.y" backgroundColor="#F60D0D"/>
    <mx:Canvas x="629" y="168" id="location2" width="200" height="200"
        click="playerX = location2.x, playerY = location2.y" backgroundColor="#EDE513"/>
    <mx:Canvas id="player1" x="{playerX}" y="{playerY}"
        width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="#3458F5"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Now I'm just working on modularizing it to achieve my real end goal, which is making sure I understand how events, objects, and event objects work.

Comment: What values do evt.x and evt.y end up with?

Comment: CookieOfFortune, I can't even get to that point because it won't let me compile until I've resolved the errors I mentioned below in re Eric's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define a custom event class called PlayerMove with the x and y properties. and as eric said, set the bubbles properties to true.

```
public class PlayerMove extends Event {

      public static const PLAYER_MOVE : String = "playerMove";
      public var x : int;
      public var y : int;

      public function PlayerMove(x:int, y:int; type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false) {
             super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
             this.x = x;
             this.y = y;
      }
}
```

also, on your player canvas where you have the mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="200" height="200"
    **click="clickHandler()"** you must add the *event* keyword to the function like **click="clickHandler(event)"** and same to your function

```
private function clickHandler(event : MouseEvent) : void {
   dispatchEvent(new PlayerMove(event.target.x, event.target.y, PlayerMove.PLAYER_MOVE));
}
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

You're not bubbling the event, so the parent document (the application) isn't "hearing" it.

Try changing this:

```
var moveClick:Event = new Event("playerMove");
```

to this:

```
var moveClick:Event = new Event("playerMove", true);
```

The added `true` sets the `bubbles` property of the event to true.

Comment: Although that's probably one of my problem, Eric, it isn't my only one since the 'moveClick.x = target.x;' and the line immediately after it are both giving me 1119 and 1120 errors.  I assume the issue is either one the left hand side, that moveClick doesn't have an 'x' or 'y' parameter, or on the right hand side where 'target' isn't referencing the canvas itself like I want it to.